# Kentico 7 MVC View paths wrong for resources in masterpage

Tags: kentico

I'm using an MVC controller and view to facilitate custom routing in Kentico 7.

The only issue with this is that content in the master page is referenced from https://{site}/{page}/~/{normal path from root} instead of https://{site}/{normal path from root}

Page route in CMSDesk:
/page/{param1}

View in filesystem:
\Views\Global\Page\Page\Page.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Views_Global_Page"
    MasterPageFile="Root.master" %>
```

\Views\Global\Page\Page\Page.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using CMS.CMSHelper;
using CMS.GlobalHelper;
using CMS.PortalControls;
using Saxon.Api;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;
using CMS.URLRewritingEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;

public partial class Views_Global_Page : ViewPage
{
}
```

Controller on filesystem:
\App_Code\Controllers\Global\PageController.cs

```
namespace CMS.Controllers.Global
{
    public class PageController : Controller
    {
        ...
        public ActionResult Index(string param = "")
        {
            ...
            return View("Page/Page");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Could you provide more pieces of information what is a problem and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are displaying some content which is edited by WYSIWYG, is that correct?

If so, you need to run this content through HTMLHelper.ResolveUrls method, because it is stored with relative links which need to be resolved.